# List instances that belong to one vpc

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to attach some security groups to some ec2 instances, but I have multiple vpc-s, and I want to attach them to instances that belong to a particular vpc.

How should I modify my script to get only these instances?

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = ec2.instances.filter()
for instance in instances:
   print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
   all_sg_ids = [sg['GroupId'] for sg in instance.security_groups]
   if sg_id not in all_sg_ids: 
       all_sg_ids.append(sg_id)
       instance.modify_attribute(Groups=all_sg_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in the meantime:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
vpc_id="vpc-0abcde1"
instances = instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'vpc-id', 'Values': [vpc_id]}])
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type, instance.vpc_id)
    all_sg_ids = [sg['GroupId'] for sg in instance.security_groups]
    # for allsg in all_sg_ids:
    #   print (allsg)
    if sg_id not in all_sg_ids: 
        all_sg_ids.append(sg_id)
        instance.modify_attribute(Groups=all_sg_ids)
```